# Filter out dictionary elements with specific key in a nested list

Tags: javascript, node.js, list, lambda, filter

I have a nested list that looks like:

```
var data = [[
    {item: 'top_X', pos:1},
    {name: 'person1', value: 1},
    {name: 'person2', value: 1}
],[
    {item: 'top_Y', pos:1},
    {name: 'person1', value: 2},
    {name: 'person2', value: 2}
],[
    {item: 'top_Z', pos:1},
    {name: 'person1', value: 1}
] ];
```

in `js`, I am trying to use a lambda function that filters out each `dictionary` in the `data` *list* and returns the same structure but without the `dictionary` where `item` key is present.

```
 all = data.map(x => {
        return x; // returns the whole list
    });

    //
    fileredOutList = data.map(x => {
       return x.filter  ?? ..
    }); // Expected output list: 
 //      data = [[{name: 'person1', value: 1},
 //              {name: 'person2', value: 1}],
 //             [{name: 'person1', value: 2},
 //              {name: 'person2', value: 2}],
 //             [{name: 'person1', value: 1}]]


fileredOutListCount = data.map(x => {
   //  return x.filter  ?? .. .count()
   // return count elements after filter --> 3
});
```

How can I build an inline function to **filter in a sub-list** and return another (filtered) list and/or the `count` after the filtering.

Sorry for the simple question, I am new to `JS` and I am stuck with this simple task.

Comment: Your requirement/question is way too complicated. You just need a function (named or anonymous) for the `.filter()` callback. It's irrelevant if the array you're calling `.filter()` on is stored in another array or an object or some custom "thing". It's still just an array.

Comment: Just test for the presence of an `item` property (`return typeof x.item === "undefined"`) in the `.filter()` callback

Comment: @Andreas `return x.item === "undefined"` or `return !(x.item)` will do the same thing, `typeof` check is useless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` for filtering out the object which has `item` property.

```js
var data = [[
    {item: 'top_X', pos:1},
    {name: 'person1', value: 1},
    {name: 'person2', value: 1}
],[
    {item: 'top_Y', pos:1},
    {name: 'person1', value: 2},
    {name: 'person2', value: 2}
],[
    {item: 'top_Z', pos:1},
    {name: 'person1', value: 1}
] ];


let out = data.map(arr => arr.filter(e => !e.hasOwnProperty('item')));
console.log(out)
```